# How would I convert or map xpath with the CSS selector?

Tags: python, xpath, css-selectors

I have code that does or finds  the label to find the file using xpath

```
 xPathToFieldBasedOnLabe="//div[text()='" + keyword + "']//parent::div//parent::div[contains(@class,'Button')]"
```

The above I want convert to CSS sector, I did mapping as follows, doesn't seems working ..

```
xPathToFieldBasedOnLabel = "div:contains(" + keyword + ").parent:div.parent:div.Button"
```

any inputs or correction to do above xpath mapping to css selector?

Comment: When you are dealing with text, CSS is not a great idea.

Comment: @supputuri, thanks for the message, but is there any way we tweak this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you could have used `ancestor` in your XPath expression :

```
//div[text()='" + keyword + "']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'Button')]
```

**You can't match the content of an element with a CSS selector. It doesn't exist.**

However there's a workaround in `scrapy` where the CSS is translated to XPath (thanks to the `cssselect` library). So for your specific case, and if you're using scrapy you could write :

```
keyword = foobar
response.css(div.Button div:contains("'+keyword+'")).get()
```

But it could be too generic and needs to be strengthen.